# Importing legacy html table design into div layout

Tags: php, css, html-table

We are in the process of importing some old pages from our legacy website which was designed in tables into our new DIV based layout.  Our site is built on a PHP include system, so we have our pages split into three components; header, body, and footer.  These old pages need to be pulled in for our launch of revision 1.0, and then as we get all of the wrinkles ironed out, we will redesign.

Our header component is working out just fine, and the body content displays as it should, but unfortunately the existing footer element plugs into the bottom of the table.  Our footer for the new design extends for 100% of the width, but the existing table only allows for 960px width.  Thus our footer is getting cut off.

We are trying to find a dynamic solution, either a using JavaScript, or the jQuery Attr() call to dynamically effect the table dimensions to allow the footer to extend to the edge of the page, yet everything I have tried does not modify the table dimensions or allow overfow to show at all.

Here are a couple of screenshots for you to see what I am talking about.

Div layout:
[image: div]

Table Layout:
[image]

If you like to take a peek at the code, you can look at my [Demo Page](http://rawdesigns.net/web2carz/legacy/), but just know that this is a demo version which is not using PHP to pull in the components.  Its a simple HTML/CSS based layout I have been using to search for alternatives. (I'm not a PHP guy)

We are trying to avoid having to go through hundreds of documents and cutting and pasting the footer in below the table, or having to modify any other code by hand.  If we could just include a CSS or JavaScript doc in the header that would render a workaround is the ideal solution.

Comment: It might be helpful to include a picture pointing out just what you don't like about the "merged" view.

Comment: I felt as though I did, but I will add some notes to the other version...

Comment: My bad, uploaded the annotated version :)

Comment: take the footer out of (div class=row) and put it inside (div class=container). (div class=row) is preventing our footer to flex its wings.

Comment: My div class="row" is not set to hide overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make a div with the footer Background - separate from the contents and underneath. Put a div with the same css styles as 'footer' after your  element. Then you can take the background image (footer_bg.jpg repeat-x) off of footer.

See campdavidozarks.org for a website I made with the same idea.

Comment: You know I had thought of that idea this morning, and that is seeming to be the best idea, though that will require us hand coding a fresh div into all of the legacy documents.  But yes I do think that is going to be a top item on our list of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Center the table, and use the same footer-background on the parent, 100% width element, too with alignment to the bottom and no-repeat on y. Done. Pure CSS solution.